# Adding a print button to a website (that will automatically set the zoom, margins, and hide header/footer for printing)

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I understand that using JavaScript and window.print() has limitations around setting certain print options (due to security issues). I also understand that CSS has the ability to set certain elements (like @page) for setting a document to landscape.

Is there a way to use CSS to set print options like zoom, margins, and hide header/footer? If so, does anyone have any code samples for doing this? If this is not possible using JS or CSS, is there any any other tools I could use to put a print button on a page that automatically sets certain print options?

**UPDATE:** Okay, I appreciate everyone's responses, and now that I have dug in a bit, I have more clarification on what I need... I do not need to modify the CSS on the page. I need to automatically set the local print options when the user clicks the button. I am in a .Net application. Any ASP.NET controls for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add another style-sheet that is specific for printing:

```
<link href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

And in that stylesheet you just put stuff like:

```
#header {
  display: none;
}
/* etc */
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't even think JS is required. You can just use the `media` attribute when linking stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

This is the stylesheet that the browser uses when it prints, and it overrides the one you see while browsing the site. Now, inside of `print.css`, you could change whatever you want and it will only affect the printed document.

As for printing, you could just make a quick button or an element which triggers `window.print()`:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="window.print()" />
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to a CSS file that will only be used for printing using the media attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Or for a inline style block:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print{
  #heading{ display:none; }
}
</style>
```